How to track down handle leak in "System" process (PID 4)
My windows computer will sometimes randomly slow down to a crawl. When this problem happens, task manager shows the System process (PID 4) having a huge number of handles. For example, this screenshot shows pid 4 having over 1 million handles:

The computer is otherwise fine - RAM usage is reasonable, disk activity seems normal and no other processes have excessive handle counts or thread counts. Killing applications and processes does not fix the slow-ness. The only way to fix it is to reboot.
My computer is Windows 11, 23H2, OS Build 22631.4169. This problem has been happening for 6+ months, so it's not a new problem introduced by a recent windows update. It is a Dell laptop that I reboot a couple times a week. The problem normally happens after the computer has been on for a few hours to a few days.
I assume there is a handle leak somewhere, but how do I figure out which piece of software on the computer is the culprit? I understand that the 'System' process is a special process, so are these handles legitimately owned by / opened by pid 4? Or are these handles somehow being mis-attributed to pid 4?
How can I view what these handles are? I have tried a few tools but they all fail to list the handles for pid 4. For example, I have tried 'handle' from the Sysinternals Suite. I have also tried Process Hacker 2. Although I'm able to view the handle list for other processes, I'm unable to view it for pid 4.

Edit: I followed Greg Askew's suggestion from the comment. Currently, Task Manager shows this:

And the output from the handle command is this:
C:\tools\SysinternalsSuite>handle -s -p 4

Nthandle v4.22 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2019 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Handle type summary:
  <Unknown type>  : 82
  <Unknown type>  : 1
  <Unknown type>  : 72
  <Unknown type>  : 31
  <Unknown type>  : 21
  <Unknown type>  : 21
  <Unknown type>  : 9
  <Unknown type>  : 18
  <Unknown type>  : 33
  <Unknown type>  : 21
  <Unknown type>  : 11
  ALPC Port       : 133
  Desktop         : 2
  Directory       : 43
  Event           : 1190
  File            : 769
  IoCompletion    : 1084
  Job             : 6
  Key             : 209
  Mutant          : 1
  Process         : 1963
  Section         : 64
  Semaphore       : 18
  SymbolicLink    : 436
  Thread          : 328749
  WaitCompletionPacket: 1111

So it seems like my extra handles are thread handles. I can use Process Explorer to look at the threads list of PID4, and it seems like there are only a few hundred threads (as Task Manager reports). However, some of the TIDs seem rather high:

Does a thread having a TID of 1283936 mean it's the 320,984th thread to be created? If so, is this abnormal?

Start with using Sysinternals Handle.exe to get a list of the type of handles associated with the system process: handle -s -p 4 > C:\handles.txt https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

@GregAskew Thanks! This is exactly the kind of suggestion I was looking for. I've just tried it and the results are interesting. I've edited my question to add additional information, including the output of handle -s -p 4 and some additional pictures. Can you let me know what you think? And whether you have any ideas as to WHY my pid4 has so many thread handles? I assume there is some other software on my computer that is causing this but how do I go about figuring out what the culprit is?

Could be a software defect. What does your EDR app tell you?
